# c# console app crating public static class and in this class make another static method

Tags: c#

How to create a public static class called Test1. This class contains a static method called Test2 which accepts three integers as an input, and returns a string as an out. 
how can i Call this in my program.cs

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should start by looking at a tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_classes.htm

Answer (score 2):

To create a static class, you just put the word "static" before the word "class" when you create the class. For static methods, the word static is right before the return type (string in this case). To call a static method, you just use class.method. For example, it would be Test1.Test2 for your code.

```
public static class Test1
{
    public static string Test2(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string result = Test1.Test2(1, 2, 3);
    }
}
```